# Downloading geoid chgeo2004?

Tags: data, geotiff-tiff, geoid, switzerland

Does anyone know where I could download geoids? Specifically I need the Swiss Geoid CHGeo2004.

I found this link: https://opendata.swiss/de/dataset/geoidmodell-chgeo2004-in-ch19031

But it only includes a RGB TIFF and some contour lines, which I guess is only for visualization.

Comment: Here's the link to the [ETRS89-based version](https://opendata.swiss/de/dataset/geoidmodell-chgeo2004-in-etrs891/resource/6c589d49-f177-4d86-b1d1-71001b595e1c). They both contain a tif file. There's a legend corresponding to the file. Otherwise, ISG says the geoid models are private--you'll have to ask SwissTopo.

Comment: this is basically the same project I found, just in a different reference system. maybe swisstopo is the key, but I was hoping for an easy download.

Answer (score 1):

Not the official source, but working:

https://www.eye4software.com/files/geoids/CHGEO04A.zip from [Eye4software](https://www.eye4software.com/hydromagic/documentation/geoid-models/)

You can download a demo verion of the Hydromagic software from https://www.eye4software.com/download/

It includes a geoid converter freeware: https://www.eye4software.com/hydromagic/documentation/manual/utilities/geoid-file-conversion/

Supported file types are `.geo, .ggf, .gsf, .byn, .bin, .grd, .txt, .gtx` as source and destination.

Disclosure: I'm not affiliated with the software company.

Answer (score 0):

Swisstopo now releases the geoid in various variations using ARC/INFO ASCII GRID files under a CC0 license.
You can convert those using QGIS to the format you need.

https://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/en/knowledge-facts/surveying-geodesy/geoid.html